# how to get request HTTP headers in soaplib views file?

Tags: python, httprequest, soaplib

i have soaplib for webservice as soap [server], all request route and response as xml by url well.but i can't fetch request http headers, How can i get request HTTP headers for rendering view some method of class ?

> like this method :

```
def redirect_http(self,request):
    return render(request, 'ask/redirect.html', {
        ''' 'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.", '''
    })
```

**Code Project :**

> soap.py

```
'''
documentation in http://soaplib.github.com/soaplib/2_0/
'''
import base64
import soaplib
from soaplib.core import Application
from soaplib.core.model import primitive as soap_types
from soaplib.core.service import DefinitionBase
from soaplib.core.service import rpc as soapmethod
from soaplib.core.server import wsgi
from soaplib.core.model.clazz import ClassModel
from soaplib.core.model.clazz import Array

from django.http import HttpResponse

# the class with actual web methods

# the class which acts as a wrapper between soaplib WSGI functionality and Django
class DjangoSoapApp(wsgi.Application):
    def __call__(self, request):
        # wrap the soaplib response into a Django response object
        django_response = HttpResponse()
        def start_response(status, headers):
            status, reason = status.split(' ', 1)
            django_response.status_code = int(status)
            for header, value in headers:
                django_response[header] = value
        response = super(DjangoSoapApp, self).__call__(request.META, start_response)
        django_response.content = '\n'.join(response)
        return django_response

class SoapView(DefinitionBase):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls):
        soap_application = Application([cls], __name__)
        return DjangoSoapApp(soap_application)


# the view to use in urls.py
#my_soap_service = DjangoSoapApp([MySOAPService], __name__)
```

> views.py

```
from soap import SoapView
from soap import soapmethod
from soap import soap_types, Array
class MySoapService(SoapView):
    __tns__ = '[url]http://localhost:8989/api/soap/verify.wsdl[/url]'
    @soapmethod(soap_types.String, soap_types.Integer, returns=soap_types.String)
    def request_verify(self, q, id, uri):
        #Some Code
        return 'some return'
my_soap_service = MySoapService.as_view()
```

> urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
import views

# Main URL Patterns
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^verify', views.my_soap_service),
  url(r'^verify.wsdl', views.my_soap_service),
]
```

Comment: problem resolved : change method request (for generate html and get http header most Observe protocol HTTP and structure), so to request and response html content should be send http request and get all headers generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved : change method request (for generate html and get http header most Observe protocol HTTP and structure), so to request and response html content should be send http request and get all headers generated